# Golang define array of bytes holding single letters

Tags: arrays, go, character, letter

I am trying to define an array of explicit fixed length (duh), and pre-populate it with values in a single line. I have come up with the following (which fails), but cannot find any documentation regarding how to do this in a single line.

`var vowels [6]byte = {"a","e","i","o","u","y"}`

I also do **NOT** want to use the `:=` operator.

**ANSWER** - derivative of answer by *@peterSO* for code readability.

```
var vowels = [6]byte{'a','e','i','o','u','y'}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to work with multi-character strings, I'm going after single character (letters) only. Slices use arrays under the hood anyways, so wouldn't this be necessary?

Comment: As for documentation, it's all laid out in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec), You can see some array examples under [Composite Literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) and  [Array Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types), which also both define the grammar.

Comment: It is far less readable because `[10]byte{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}` is valid too. When you write `[6]byte{'a','e','i','o','u','y'}` I have to carefully count the vowels to make sure there are exactly six of them. Writing `[...]byte{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}` lets the compiler and computer do the counting. They are much more reliable and untiring than you or I.

Comment: An equivalent alternative would be `[]byte("aeiouy")`. It's more concise but slightly less explicit. Also, answers should be in answers, not edited into questions.

Answer (score 4):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var vowels = [...]byte{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}
    fmt.Printf("%d %c\n", len(vowels), vowels)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Giok8PkpItR

Output:

```
6 [a e i o u y]
```